# Completion block with multiple params in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, completionhandler

In my application I use `Retrofit` to make a network call and I pass a completion block to the wrapping function:

```
fun issueToken(phoneNumber: String, otp: String,completion:(token: Token?, errorString: String) -> Unit) { //TODO: return something??
    retrofitInstance.issueToken(LOGIN_GRANT_TYPE, LOGIN_CLIENT_ID,LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET,phoneNumber, otp).enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<IssueTokenResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<IssueTokenResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            completion(null, "NetworkManger: issueToken failed")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<IssueTokenResponse>, response: retrofit2.Response<IssueTokenResponse>) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {

                AccountManager.token.mAccessToken = response.body()?.access_token
                AccountManager.token.mRefreshToken = response.body()?.refresh_token
                AccountManager.token.mExpirationDate =
                    response.body()?.expires_in?.plus((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L));
                completion(AccountManager.token, "")

            } else {
                //TODO
                completion(null, "NetworkManager: issueToken response code = " + response.code() + " message = " + response.message() )
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Now, I'm not sure how to call the `issueToken` method with the completion block, as I am new to `Kotlin`. I tried something like that:

```
NetworkManager.issueToken(view.phoneNumber.text.toString(),view.otp_edit_text_id.text.toString())  token, errorString -> { ... }
```

But I get errors that says:

```
No value passed for parameter 'completion'
```

I also have errors on this part:

```
token, errorString ->
```

What is the correct way to call the function with the completion block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to read [kotlin lambda conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#lambdas) first.

You should call like that:

```
issueToken(view.phoneNumber.text.toString(),view.otp_edit_text_id.text.toString()) { token: Token?, errorString: String ->

}
```

You may also use like that:

```
 val completion = { token: Token?, errorString: String ->
    // define whatever you need
 }

 issueToken(view.phoneNumber.text.toString(),view.otp_edit_text_id.text.toString(), completion)
```